# how to read java documentation comment using Java Program

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am creating a java program that take inputs path of JAR and display the classes, methods (in that JAR) in a suitable format. I've accomplished it using java.lang.reflect. Now I also need to read Documentation Comment provided by the Developer and display them. Is it possible to read it?

Comment: Greatly depends on the documentation. No way to tell without specification what type of documentation you are talking about.

Comment: If you're talking about javadoc, you can't access that from the compiled code anymore (and certainly not with reflection).

Comment: Java Documentation comment (/** */) I want to read such comments using a java program

Comment: But you haven't said why. In any case the Javadoc isn't in the JAR file, so you can't.

Comment: What if I've source code with me then I would be able to read it.

Comment: I'm generating my own online documentation by reading input jars and creating a customized java documentation. problem is i am not able to read java documentation comments

Comment: Then you'd need to parse the source code for the documentations and link those to the other information you have.

Comment: If you have the source code somewhere it is now a completely different question. You need to have a look at the Doclet API, via the Javadoc home page.

Comment: ok let me try Doclet API

Comment: With the doclet you can generate documentaiton from the javadoc from the sources (not from the jar though). In this case it will also add the classes and methods and you won't have to do that reflection stuff ;) but if you have the sources it is completely different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are talking about the javadoc. Unfortunately it is not packed in the .class files so it is not in the JAR. You can generate javadoc in readable format from the sources only and then add them to the JAR in some kind of readable format. For example using doclet

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. What I am actually planning to do is this: 1) A Separate Java Program let's called it A.java. A.java when executed will ask for JAR Path. 2) If JAR Path is provided it would read and generate HTML files right now I am able to generate HTML files with classes and methods But I am not able to read comments using reflection. So can you help me in knowing how to read it?

Comment: That's what I am saying. By default the javadoc comments is NOT in the JAR file. So you cannot read them using reflection. Your option is to have pre-generated javadoc in readable form - html or something which is added to the JAR file explicitly and use that one.